# change color of multiple labels

Tags: java, netbeans-8, foreground

I have a java panel with a large number of jLabels.  The user can change the colour of these labels from a 'theme' pick list.  Is there a way of changing them all in one go or do I have to set the foreground colour for each one separately.

Comment: You can use a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with something like this:

```
for (JLabel label : labelList) {
    label.setForeground(Color.RED); // or any other color
}
```

Comment: That helps but how do I set the labelList variable?

Comment: It's just a collection of your labels. For example `List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();` and add all `JLabel`s to the list.